# Is it safe to install Service Pack 1 update on an already dual booted windows 7 and ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I wanted to install the Service Pack 1 update on my already dual booted Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. I just wanted to make sure if doing this is safe or not? I had followed [this tutorial](http://bhrigu.me/blog/2015/06/22/how-to-install-ubuntu-with-dual-boot-easy-step-wise-guide/) to perform the dual boot. After following the tutorial I was booting directly into Windows and had to use boot repair and grub customizer to fix the related issues. Any suggestions as to what I must do to prevent any problems that I might encounter?

Edit - Please allow me to delete this question from here before I can post it on superuser.

Comment: What is a "Service Pack 1"? Mind that you are on a site dedicated to Ubuntu. Installing software inside Windows is not our cup of tea. Any answer would be conjecture since Windows is not the easiest system to update. Make backups is all we can advice :)

Comment: Service Pack 1 is a cumulative update for Windows 7. It has nothing to do with ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rinzwind says, backup, backup, backup.  Have an Ubuntu live-media available to reinstall grub (very likely).  Know the sector start/end of every partition on your disk (may ease recovery of a working filesystem in some cases).  Know the packages you installed, so you can recreate the system from scratch (backup usually applies to just your files, but setting up a customized system is not necessarily trivial).  Assume the worst, and be ready to recovery.  Maybe absolutely nothing will happen to grub or your partitions/files, but maybe they will all be grabbed by Windows and made into "Recovery" partitions -- be ready to deal with that.