# Will resetting my Windows 10 (which is installed along with Ubuntu), mess up boot settings files?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I believe when we install Ubuntu alongside windows 10, a boot section is created with ubuntu boot settings alongside windows 10 boot section. If this section gets messed up somehow, the 'choose OS' options that come up when booting PC, won't show up & pc will load windows automatically (that happened before for me).
My question is, if I reset my Windows 10 through `Settings -> Update & Security -> Recovery -> Reset this PC`, will it mess up boot files as well. I am not talking about using a bootable usb or dvd, but resetting through the Windows 10 internal settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) and [Is it safe to install Service Pack 1 update on an already dual booted windows 7 and ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/845132/)

Comment: It could well mess things up GRUB-wise. Eg if you install Windows after Ubuntu then that issue would occur. If this happens after a Win10 reset then a boot-repair from Live Ubuntu should fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know resetting Windows doesn't touch the boot partition. It should only remove installed programs, check Windows files, and if the option is selected remove user files.

It **should** be safe to reset Windows without affecting Grub or Ubuntu.

Comment: I have windows 10 and Ubuntu dual booting at the moment. I need to reset windows due to previous company account locked down. So in about 20 mins I can say whether the reset stops me from dual booting or not.. fingers crossed!

Comment: Can confirm, the Ubuntu data is all in tact after a full reset of the Windows files! Phew.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting windows 10 which is installed along with ubuntu, through `Windows Settings -> Update & Security -> Recovery -> Reset this PC`, does not mess up boot files (at least not for me). I was successfully able to reset the PC, and no damage to boot files happened. I still get option to chose Ubuntu or Windows when booting my PC.